# Handles leak when loading/unloading FFMPEG library in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ffmpeg, handle-leak, lavfilters

I currently have a problem loading/unloading the avfilter-7.dll from ffmpeg 4.22 (x86)
using Delphi 2007 (also with Delphi XE3..same problem)

Each loading / unloading process of the library causes a handles leak
in Windows x64 Pro for which I currently have no explanation or solution.
I have already tried to upgrade to a newer version of the DLL but the leak is even worse,
strangely, a very old version (avfilter-2.dll) is not affected by this

```
    dllLHandle := LoadLibrary(PAnsiChar('c:\Windows\SysWow64\AVFilter-7.dll'));
    if dllLHandle<>0 then begin
       FreeLibrary(dllLHandle);
       dllLHandle:= 0;
    end;
```

The code above causes an additional leak with each call

Is there something wrong, have I forgotten something?

Comment: How are you certain one handle leaks? Have you used [ProcExp or Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see the handle's type/details?

Comment: yes,  the memory leak refers to open semaphores it seems

Comment: [Browse existing bug tickets](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/query?status=new&status=open&status=reopened&col=id&col=summary&col=status&col=type&col=component&col=version&col=time&col=changetime&report=1&desc=1&order=time) and if you don't find any similar to your issue try submitting one.

Comment: Process Explorer also gives the handle names and details not just the type.